# can't install boost 1.59 using brew

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew

brew : 2.5.0

os : macos 10.15.6

when I execute the command `brew install boost@1.59`

error happends that `Error: boost@1.59 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!`

I have install the `boost` that version is `1.73.0`

Comment: Got the same error today. Guess just download it from [boost](https://www.boost.org/users/history/)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I guess this is the [reason](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/8d3c5b94596bd091ebf7945f10a19115aed5a98d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the boost@1.59 has been disabled.[see](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/8d3c5b94596bd091ebf7945f10a19115aed5a98d#commitcomment-42219869)

If we still need it, we can build our own brew repo.

I have create a [repo](https://github.com/JokerSun/homebrew-my.git) which checked `boost@1.59.rb` out from offical repo and enable it.

Then open the terminal, include your repo `brew tap [user]/[repo] [url]` and install it.

e.g.

```sh
brew tap jokersun/my https://github.com/JokerSun/homebrew-my.git

brew update

brew search boost@1.59
> jokersun/my/boost@1.59 ✔

brew install jokersun/my/boost@1.59
```

It will compile and intall into your pc for many minutes (It takes about 10m on my mac).

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this issue myself. I resolved it by:

```
brew edit boost@1.59
```

The Formula `*.rb` will open in your code editor. At that point, remove the line:

```
disable! because: :versioned_formula
```

Save it.

Run:

```
brew install boost@1.59
```

Optional:

```
brew link boost@1.60
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. I've made some updates to your formatting to aid in readability. Please review to both make sure my edits are appropriate, but also to learn how to format your posts in the future. Notably, I was unclear on the syntax of the `*.rb` file; should that entire line be treated as a code block? If not, please feel free to edit as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much @JeremyCaney , appreciate your kind input and I shall follow your footsteps in future posts and keeping to the format. *.rb is the file extension of the file that I was referring to and you have done it justice with your take on its formatting, thank you again.